# Out of memory in MySQL error log

Tags: mysql, memory, log

What should I check to solve this error that appears in the error log?
Do I need to add RAM to the server or adjust some configuration variable?

I copy part of the log:

> 180102 10:45:53  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 267632652
>   mysql3: Out of memory (Needed 2299002880 bytes)
>
> 180102 10:45:54 [Note] mysql3: ready for connections. Version:
>   '5.0.27-community-log'  socket: ''  port: 3307  MySQL Community
>   Edition (GPL)
>
> 180102 10:46:14180102 10:46:14 [ERROR] Cannot find table
>   test/cliconcepw from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the
>   .frm file for the table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated
>   InnoDB data files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm
>   files of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another
>   database?
>
> See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
>   how you can resolve the problem.
>
> 180215 20:15:05 [ERROR] Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other
>   process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use
>   'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap
>   space

---

Windows Server 2008 64 bits / 8 GB RAM

### MySQL 5.0

Comment: So, did you "see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html"? What did you try?

Comment: Let's see your `my.cnf`.  Is MySQL, itself, 64-bit?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ver%';`

Comment: version: 5.0.27-community-log

Comment: @rick-james **version**: 5.0.27-community-log / **version_comment**: MySQL Community Edition (GPL) / **version_compile_machine**: ia32 / **version_compile_os**: Win32, thanks.-

Answer (score 0):

A 32-bit MySQL on a 64-bit OS in 8GB of RAM:

- The OS can access all 8GB.
- The 32-bit MySQL is given no more than 4GB; it is impossible for it to use more than that.  Actually, it can't quite use all 4GB.
- You could (should) reconfigure MySQL (via `my.cnf`) as if it were on a 4GB machine.
- You could get a 64-bit version of MySQL
- You could upgrade MySQL -- 5.0 is really antique.  Even 5.1 is 'dead'.  There is 5.5, rapidly aging, 5.6, 5.7, and soon 8.0.

More on configuring memory:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory